# Print 2 ArrayLists Side by Side

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have created 2 ArrayLists of the same size (5) and i want to print out their contents side by side in columns.
For example:

```
list 1 = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
list 2 = [5 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 1]
```

I want to print it out to the console like this:

```
1    5
2    4
3    3
4    2
5    1
```

I have tried using a for loop within another for loop but I think I may be overthinking it.

Comment: Please post your code (you can edit your question and add it there) so it;s easier to help you.

Comment: @Keppil: This edit is not necessary. The code provided was pseudocode and is of invalid syntax in terms of Java.

Comment: @Unihedro: Somthing had to be done to make it look the way OP intended. In what way did I say it is Java?

Answer (score 3):

Since, you need the lists to print side by side nested loops are not required.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d\t%d\n", list1.get(i), list2.get(i));
}
```

Notice, the loop assumes that the two lists are of the same size. So, we need only one loop counter.

***Output :***

```
1   5
2   4
3   3
4   2
5   1
```